# Is there a way to add more image url in set_image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def hug(ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):

    hug_embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f'❤️ {ctx.author.display_name} hugged {user.display_name} ❤️',
        description=' ',
        color=0xcce5ff)
    hug_embed.set_image(
        url=
        'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/787005334560309269/850480213111341056/hug_ghot.gif'
    )
    hug_embed.set_footer(text='hi')

    if user:
        await ctx.message.channel.send(embed=hug_embed)
    else:
        await ctx.send('hug someone ;n;')
```

Is there a way to add more image URLs, and when people run the command it displays a random one every time?

eg. https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/759127214745845774/850148274262507520/cat_hug.gif

Comment: Create a list with all the links and then choose random out of it. (`images = ["Link1", "Link2" ...]` + `random.choice(images)`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
import random
image_list = ["url", "url2", "url3", etc.]
```

inside command:

```py
hug_embed.set_image(
    url=random.choice(image_list)
)
```

choice will randomly pick an element of `image_list` to set as the image URL